# Project wont run in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm doing the beginner android course on udacity and the code that they make you put in the MainActivity.java file is full of errors and keeps saying build failed in the console. Here is a link to a screenshot of android studio after failed build
http://postimg.org/image/6etcu6ldz/

Comment: Paste down you error log. Btw right click on the project > Android Tools > Install support library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think support library is missing.

Go to your build.gradle (Module:app) and check if support library is in dependencies section.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
}
```

In addition, you have to install it in SDK Manager.

I hope this answer will help you!